# Including a stylesheet in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

For some reason my stylesheet isn't being included on my webpage. I'm new to php so maybe my code is wrong. This is how I've tried to do it;

```
function my_css(){
        wp_register_style( 'my_styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/my_styles.css' );
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_css' );
```

Comment: Please refer this https://wp.zacgordon.com/2013/03/13/adding-css-to-wordpress-theme-via-functions-php-file/

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, you have to further enqueue style after register it,

```
function my_css(){
        wp_register_style( 'my_styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/my_styles.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my_styles' );
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_css' );
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code to add the stylesheet on page.

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my_styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/my_styles.css' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: What should the OP "use the following code"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.